# Рекурсивный алгоритм. Переполнение стека. OpenGL. C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-studio, visual-c++, opengl

Написал алгоритм для отрисовки треугольника Серпинского, но после ввода координат основного треугольника и кол-ва рекурсий мне компилятор выдает необработанное исключение (переполнение стека)

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00BB1D33 в OpenGL_app1.exe: 0xC000041D: Во время обратного вызова пользователя обнаружено необработанное исключение., произошло

Сам код:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

////////////////////////////////////////////////

double coord_for_triangle[6];
int cout_recursion;

////////////////////////////////////////////////

void draw_line(double x_1, double y_1, double x_2, double y_2)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2d(x_1, y_1);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2d(x_2, y_2);

    glEnd();
}
void draw_triangle (double x_1, double y_1, double x_2, double y_2, double x_3, double y_3)
{
    draw_line(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2);
    draw_line(x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3);
    draw_line(x_3, y_3, x_1, y_1);
}
void draw_the_Sierpinski_triangle(double x_1, double y_1, double x_2, double y_2, double x_3, double y_3, double cout_recursion)
{
    double new_x_1, new_y_1, new_x_2, new_y_2, new_x_3, new_y_3;
    new_x_1 = (x_1 + x_2) / 2;
    new_y_1 = (y_1 + y_2) / 2;
    new_x_2 = (x_2 + x_3) / 2;
    new_y_2 = (y_2 + y_3) / 2;
    new_x_3 = (x_3 + x_1) / 2;
    new_y_3 = (y_3 + y_1) / 2;
    draw_triangle(new_x_1, new_y_1, new_x_2, new_y_2, new_x_3, new_y_3);
    draw_the_Sierpinski_triangle(x_1, y_1, new_x_2, new_y_2, new_x_3, new_y_3, cout_recursion - 1);
    draw_the_Sierpinski_triangle(x_2, y_2, new_x_1, new_y_1, new_x_3, new_y_3, cout_recursion - 1);
    draw_the_Sierpinski_triangle(x_3, y_3, new_x_1, new_y_1, new_x_2, new_y_2, cout_recursion - 1);
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, w, 0, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLineWidth(2);

    draw_the_Sierpinski_triangle(coord_for_triangle[0], coord_for_triangle[1], coord_for_triangle[2], coord_for_triangle[3], coord_for_triangle[4], coord_for_triangle[5], cout_recursion);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    cout << "Размеры окна: 1000 x 800" << endl
         << "Введите 6 координат для построения основного треугольника:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
    {
        cin >> coord_for_triangle[i];
    }

    cout << endl << "Укажите необходимое кол-во рекурсия для построения труегольников:" << endl;
    cin >> cout_recursion;

    if (cout_recursion <= 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL_APP");

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это не удивительно, ведь рекурсия (которая зло) ничем не ограничивается.

Comment: ну а какая проблема переделать на цикл?

Comment: или хотя бы проверять глубну рекурсии в рекурсивной функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции

```
void draw_the_Sierpinski_triangle(double x_1, double y_1,
                                  double x_2, double y_2,
                                  double x_3, double y_3,
                                  double cout_recursion)
{
```

следует добавить проверку - а не слишком ли близки точки. Что-то вроде

```
if (abs(x_1 - x2) < eps || 
    abs(x_1 - x3) < eps || 
    abs(x_3 - x2) < eps) return;
```

Comment: ну и наверное проверку на глубину рекурсии тоде добавить не лишнее, а то параметр `cout_recursion` есть, но не используется.

Comment: @tym32167 Тогда она может оборваться или слишком рано, или слушком поздно.

Comment: тогда смысла в том параметре? Если он не используется и не нужен, то наверное его можно просто выпилить из кода

Comment: @tym32167 Это пусть автор выпиливает - мложет ему надо найти максимальную глубину?...

Comment: да я не против, просто отметил, что в текущей реализации поле смысла не имеет